# Check if value exist in database and alert message

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a data base containing following data

[image: :]

I have a textbox to enter chqNo. How to display the status according to chqNo entered in textbox.Foreg: If we enter 5 it should alert "cancelled" otherwise "active" on textbox onchange() using angularJs

Comment: Any code ? The thing you want to do will require logic all over from data-layer to presentation layer to user view. You need to be more precise with your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have cheque information fetched from database and stored in a `$scope` object in angularjs.

```
$scope.chequeInfo = [
    {chqNo: 1, custName : 'Bikash', status : 'active'},
    {chqNo: 2, custName : 'Bikash', status : 'active'},
    {chqNo: 3, custName : 'Bikash', status : 'active'},
    {chqNo: 4, custName : 'Bikash', status : 'active'},
    {chqNo: 5, custName : 'Bikash', status : 'cancelled'}
];


$scope.onChqChange = function(chqNo) {
  angular.forEach($scope.chequeInfo, function(cheque) {
    if(cheque.chqNo === chqNo) {
       alert(cheque.status);
    }
  });
};
```

Bound the method to your HTML as:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="chqNo" ng-change="onChqChange(chqNo)"/>
```

See the [Working demo here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/J4a9asbPdMy3X4CzepOZ?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, I returned data from my action result:See Here 
        https://plnkr.co/edit/mU3lcnQTCehPG0HyVJcP?p=preview